# Having issue to resolve - subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table that needs to be updated.

With the below table as example. I would want to update all the patternID 2 using the patternid 1.
But when i try to use the sub query> I am getting the error "subquery returned more than 1 value"

Query used

```
update Testtable 
set triggertime = (select triggertime from testtable where patternid = 1 )
where patternid = 2
```

Please help

Below is the test table

```
PatternID   triggertime ro_no
1   00:30       101
2   00:45       101
3   01:00       101
1   00:30       102
2   00:50       102
3   01:00       102
1   00:30       103
2   00:51       103
3   01:00       103
1   00:30       105
2   00:52       105
3   01:00       105
1   00:30       104
2   00:53       104
3   01:00       104
1   00:30       106
2   00:54       106
3   01:00       106
```

Comment: Assuming there are multiple rows that satisfy `where patternid = 1` condition, which one do you want to use to get `triggertime` value from?

Comment: Maybe add a `LIMIT 1` to your subquery?

Comment: Based on the 3rd column RO_no.

Comment: @user3575799: "Based on the 3rd column RO_no" --- what does it mean? It's empty

Comment: @user3575799 , WHICH RDBMS?

Comment: example am updating patternID 1 for all the ro_no.....based on the ro_no grouped by.

Comment: @user3575799, is it my sql  or sql server or oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
UPDATE testtable 
SET triggertime = (SELECT TOP 1 T2.triggertime
                   FROM testtable T2
                   WHERE T2.patternid = 1
                        AND T2.ro_no = T.ro_no
                   ORDER BY T2.triggertime DESC)
FROM testtable T
WHERE patternid = 2
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @user3575799 It's a pleasure to help but next time i suggest you to take a bit more time on your description. We can't help you if you don't provide every information like the RDBMS, a data sample, the expected result, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like it says, there are multiple `paternnid = 1` rows. Which one do you want to use? Maybe the max one?

Try this:

```
update Testtable 
set triggertime = (select max(triggertime) from testtable where patternid = 1 )
where patternid = 2
```

*Edit*

Based on your new description:

```
update Testtable 
set triggertime = (select max(innerTable.triggertime) from testtable innerTable where innertable.patternid = 1 and innerTable.ro_no = outerTable.ro_no )
from Testtable outerTable
where patternid = 2;
```

See:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ede5a/1

Comment: I need to update all the patternid 1 to patternid 2 based or group by ro_no

Comment: Again, *which* one? Can you show what the table should look like AFTER the update runs?

Comment: Before     After  
PatternID triggertime ro_no  PatternID triggertime ro_no
1 00:30 101  1 00:45 101
2 00:45 101  2 00:45 101
3 01:00 101  3 01:00 101
1 00:30 102  1 00:50 102
2 00:50 102  2 00:50 102
3 01:00 102  3 01:00 102
1 00:30 103  1 00:51 103
2 00:51 103  2 00:51 103
3 01:00 103  3 01:00 103
1 00:30 105  1 00:52 105
2 00:52 105  2 00:52 105
3 01:00 105  3 01:00 105
1 00:30 104  1 00:53 104
2 00:53 104  2 00:53 104
3 01:00 104  3 01:00 104
1 00:30 106  1 00:54 106
2 00:54 106  2 00:54 106
3 01:00 106  3 01:00 106